# Какой тип данных использовать для вещественных чисел в mysql?

Tags: mysql

С mysql почти не работал. Какой тип данных лучше выбрать для чисел, имеющих какое-то кол-во знаков после запятой? Пример числа: `37.4044`. Я так понял, в mysql несколько типов данных, которые подходят в данном случае. Но какой из них лучше выбрать?

Comment: float вполне подойдёт, определяет значения с плавающей запятой

Comment: Тот, который вам подходит лучше в вашей конкретной задаче. Они, в основном, различаются только размерами и диапазоном значений, которые могут принимать, как, в принципе, и в любом другом ЯП.

Comment: @РусланДраган каждому своё. Лично я зачастую использую double. В моих задачах мне он больше подходит - у меня много знаков после точки. :)

Comment: @intro94, я ничего не имею против, это был первый ответ, который пришел в голову, да и число не имеет много знаков после запятой

Comment: @РусланДраган я против `float` тоже не имею ничего против... :) Просто высказался. К тому же, то число в вопросе - это лишь пример. И он был указан, как мне кажется, для тех, кто не поймёт, что такое "число с запятой". :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При работе с дробными значениями определите сначала для своей задачи требования к точности хранения и обработки.

Если для выражения вроде `(0.1+0.7)*10` вам допустимо получить что-то вроде 7.9999999999999991118 вместо 8 - значит вы можете использовать стандарт IEEE754, т.е. типы данных float или double. Разница между ними в диапазоне хранимых значений. Изначально типы разрабатывались для научных нужд, где важна производительность, но сами величины в выражениях могут в некоторых пределах искажаться при вычислениях. Значения всё равно не точны из-за ограничений измерительной аппаратуры.

Если же речь идёт о, например, деньгах - то, разумеется, такие плавающие значения недопустимы и нужны типы данных с фиксированной запятой. Это decimal (так же известный как numeric) - вы при добавлении поля сами указываете, сколько знаков он может хранить и сколько из этих знаков являются дробной частью значения.